# Does using the Desktop 'Stacks' feature contribute to performance loss?

Tags: macos, display, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro running 6 4k monitors... Is it possible that with 1600+ Desktop icons Stacks could degrade performance?

Comment: That many Desktop icons used to.  Whether it still does, I cannot say.